# Use angular binding with kendo grid templates

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use kendo ui grid with angular. I want the grid to be updated with every change in the array (of any property). Meaning, if my data is:

```
this.rowData = [{ id: "1",  name: "A", age: "16" }, { id: "2", name: "B", age: "42" }];
```

and the age is changed from 16 to 17 I want the grid to be updated automatically.

I understand that I can use ObservableArray and when updating the observable the grid will be updated but I don't want the entire application to know the observable. I want to be able to update the original rowData and affect the grid. Any suggestions of how I do that?

I thought that adding a template to a row or a specific column with angular binding will help but it didn't, here is an example of it:

```
function Controller(GridConstants) {
    this.rowData = [{ id: "1",  name: "A", age: "16" }, { id: "2", name: "B", age: "42" }];
    this.gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: new kendo.data.ObservableArray(this.rowData),
        schema: {
            model: { id: "id" }
        }
    });

    this.gridOptions = {
        dataSource: this.gridDataSource,
        selectable: "row",
        columns: [
                    {
                        field: "name",
                        title: "Name"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "age",
                        title: "Age",
                        template: "<label>{{dataItem.age}}</label>"
                    }
        ],
        selectable: "single"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try ng-bind instead:

```
template: "<label ng-bind='dataItem.age'></label>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowDataObservable =  new kendo.data.ObservableArray(this.rowData);
```

...
data: rowDataObservable,
...
//and you need work with rowDataObservable, this will work

```
rowDataObservable[0].age = 17;
```